# Fortran makefile

Tags: makefile, fortran, fortran90

I have the following question. 
I have a set of Fortran90 source files, most of them contains modules. 
I have to build a static library (.a) out of them, and I used the following Makefile.

```
.SUFFIXES: .o .c .f90 .f .mod

DEPSF =   tt_f90m, bt
include Makefile.in #Contains compiler flags (CC, FORT, etc.)
OBJS    = $(DEPSF:,=.o).o

mytt.a: $(OBJS) 
 ar rc mytt.a $(OBJS)
.f90.o:
    $(FORT) -c $<
```

It works fine, but it has an annoying feature: if I edit any of the source files, the mytt.a target is not rebuilt. Only if I remove all .o and .mod files, it happens. The output of 
    make -d

is as follows:

```
....


Considering target file `tt_f90m.o'.
....   
Found an implicit rule for `tt_f90m.o'.
Considering target file `tt_f90m.mod'.
 Looking for an implicit rule for `tt_f90m.mod'.
....
 No implicit rule found for `tt_f90m.mod'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `tt_f90m.mod'.
No need to remake target `tt_f90m.mod'.
Finished prerequisites of target file `tt_f90m.o'.
Prerequisite `tt_f90m.mod' is older than target `tt_f90m.o'.
No need to remake target `tt_f90m.o'.
```

How can I write this makefile correctly?

Comment: I hate to nitpick, but having a really long repetitive error message in your question makes it kind of hard to read. In the future, you might want to figure out the pattern in the error messages you get and only post a few lines.

Comment: I agree, I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, I have the answer to this question.
The problem was with Fortran90.
It has .mod files as dependencies, thus if the source file is changed, the .mod
file is not, and the files are not recompiled. The solution is extremely simple.
In the beginning just write

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c .f .f90 .F90 .o
```

And that is all!

Comment: Works for me too, thanks!  Any words of wisdom on what exactly is going on here?  What does a blank SUFFIXES line do?

Comment: A blank SUFFIXES line clears out any suffixes that may have been defined earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't putting the dependence of the `.f90` and `.f` files on the `.mod` files into your makefile. If you update one of the files that ends with `.f`, `.mod` or `.c`, make doesn't see that your `.a` file depends on it, and doesn't bother to recompile the `.f90` file.

You have a few options to fix this. One is to use a tool like [makedepend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend). Makedepend itself only works for C, but fortran versions exist.

The other is to explicitly state, in your makefile, which object files depend on which module and C files. It would look a bit like this:

```
.SUFFIXES: .o .c .f90 .f .mod

DEPSF =   tt_f90m, bt
include Makefile.in #Contains compiler flags (CC, FORT, etc.)
OBJS    = $(DEPSF:,=.o).o

mytt.a: $(OBJS) 
    ar rc mytt.a $(OBJS)

ttf90m.o: bt.f90 foo.mod bar.f
    $(FORT) -c $< -o $@

bt.o: ttf90m.f90 baz.mod floop.c
    $(FORT) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: I will look at makedepend. The proposed variant (dependencies for  .o files) is good. But what if I have, say 50 source files and want to just list them in "DEPSF". And I am pretty sure that the solution above ideally worked for F77 files (without modules). Can I just tell the makefile to rebuild the .o when the corresponding source file changes?

Comment: You can add a pattern rule too, yes. But you have to be aware that the files compiled with the pattern rule won't be recompiled when one of their dependencies change.

Comment: Yes, that is what I have. So, the only thing is makedepend for fortran?

Comment: @Ivan Oseledets: Yeah,or something fancier like GNU Automake (which generates the whole makefile for you). I've never used Automake, though, and I've heard some complaints that it's hard to use.